# weka confusing StringToWordVector filter output

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I need to complete the tasks of text categorization in weka. I have the files with data in the following hierarchy.

```
mobydick
  part1
    1
    2
  part2
    1
    2
  part3
    1
    2
```

Where **1** and **2** are chucks of text of the class **partx**. I load the data with

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir mobydick > moby.arff
```

The I apply filter **StringToWordVector** with default setting and save the output.

I have a question regatrding the output. The output is following

```
...
@attribute @@class@@ {part3,part1,part2}
...
@data
{1 1,6 1,10 1...82 1,83 1}
{2 1,3 1,4 1...84 1,85 1}
{0 part1,12 1,23 1,...134 1,137 1}
{0 part1,23 1,26 1,...135 1,136 1}
{0 part2,12 1,17 1,...219 1,220 1}
{0 part2,12 1,21 1,...214 1,215 1}
```

Pretty strange output, for some reason weka placed the labels into the vectors, I expected to see something like {}, label. In addition weka didn't place label part3 in the vector, obviously it is redundant, however for simplicity it's better to place it there.

So, here I see that there is a lot of tricks, my question what the reason to do so, and if it's correct, maybe my output is result of my wrong manipulation with weka.

Answer (score 1):

Your manipulation is correct, but your expectations are different from the way WEKA format datasets.

*The class is an attribute*, the attribute to be predicted, so it is present in the vectors. It is the first attribute because of the way you have applied the filter.

The output format is sparse, that means that you get couples of attribute indexes and values for those values that are not zero. However, in the case of a nominal attribute (as the class is in this problem), you get the index and the value when the value is different to the default one, which is the first one -- `part3` in this case. As the class is the first attribute (index `0`), you get `0 part2` and `0 part1` because `part2` and `part1` are not the default ones.